# "jss-main" was not found in the current rendering data while using node-headless-ssr-proxy with React

Tags: jss, react

I am developing the JSS react template with node-headless-ssr-proxy for my company's solution, the react application have been migrated with Redux and dynamic routes, it can run and work normally in connected and disconnected mode, but when I deployed the app to ssr proxy, the browser shows below issue:
Could you help me to solve this problem, thanks!
[image]

Comment: where you able to resolve this? I am facing similar issue as well, please post your answer if this was resolved

Comment: Did you create that placeholder key item? Are renderings assigned to that placeholder?